# How to vary modal content based on button type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am absolutely confused as to why my code isn't working at the moment. I have a modal named "requestView" and I want to vary the heading of the modal (this code should make the heading change to "New message to @mdo") based on a button, but currently it doesn't work.

This is the button I have to trigger the modal RequestView:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#requestView" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>`

This is what the header of requestView looks like (I didn't include the other /div for relevancy):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="requestView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLongTitle">New message</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

My jQuery script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#requestView').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var recipient = button.data('whatever')
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
      modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
    })
</script>
```

Currently, I think the problem is that the event is not being recognized, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Where are you placing your script to add the event listener? If it's happening before the HTML loads, it won't add the event listener.

Comment: I added the script at the end of my code.

Comment: Please post your entire code, unaltered, so we may see it. In other words, we need to see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).